# Building an alarm clock style application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a webapp (referred to as the "noticeboard") for a friend's business, to aid with their packaging and dispatch operation. It is built using HTML, CSS & JS. The backend is built in PHP / MYSQL.

The noticeboard is for the benefit of their staff and displays dispatch cut-off ("event") times, i.e as follows:

- Dispatch Time 1 : `09:00`
- Dispatch Time 2 : `11:30`
- Dispatch Time 3 : `14:30`
- Dispatch Time 4 : `16:00`

They update these times on a regular basis, as their schedule depends on their delivery firm's schedule. There is an AJAX request running every 15 mins which simply fetches the latest times (JSON format) from the database and updates the noticeboard. Although I could just simply implement an "auto browser refresh" every 15 minutes, I found this was a bit inconsistent and sometimes a "page cannot be found" error message would be displayed.

The noticeboard also displays a real-time clock. I have built this using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

The system runs 24/7 in a Chrome browser running on Windows 10. Nothing else is running on the machine.

At the moment the noticeboard simply displays these times. I need to take this one step further and make it function almost like an alarm clock. What I'm basically looking to achieve is 15 minutes before each event, it needs to highlight the upcoming event time (i.e. using jQuery `addClass()`). Then as soon as that event time is reached, play a buzzer sound (some kind of MP3 file). This needs to happen **automatically every day for every event**. Remember the event times are always changing, so it would need to be smart enough to recognise this.

What techniques can I use to achieve this functionality? I have been reading up on things like `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`, however I'm not sure these are able to "auto-update" themselves once they have been set (i.e. if an event time changes). Do I need to look at a nodeJs based solution? I don't have any experience in nodeJs but if that's the best way to achieve this then I'm willing to give it a go. Otherwise I'm more than happy to try out something in vanilla JS.

Here's how I would approach it using `setTimeout()` but obviously this doesn't dynamically update:

```
// set the number of ms to 15 mins before the event time
var eventInterval = 36000000;

// setTimeout function for the event
setTimeout(function() {
    // add "active" class to highlight the event
    $('.event').addClass('active');

    // after 15 mins have elapsed, remove the "active" class
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.event').removeClass('active');
    }, 90000);
}, eventInterval;
```

Comment: sql jobs can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, however, you need to do that EVERY TIME you get an AJAX response. `setTimeout` returns a `timeoutId`, which then you can use for cancelling the timeout with `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`.

```
var reminderTime = 15 * 60 * 1000;
var timeoutIds = [];

function setTime(timestamp) {
    // Set the interval 15 minutes before the event time.
    var interval = timestamp - reminderTime;
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // add "active" class to highlight the event
        $('.event').addClass('active');

        // after 15 mins have elapsed, remove the "active" class
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.event').removeClass('active');
        }, 90000);
    }, interval);

    timeoutIds.push(timeoutId);
}

$.get("http://myserver/getTimes", function(times) {
    // Reset all the setTimeouts
    timeoutIds.forEach(function(timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    });
    // Assuming times is an array of timestamps
    times.forEach(setTime);
});
```